# Gwt-dispatch injection

Tags: gwt, dependency-injection, gwt-gin, gwt-dispatch

To use gwt-dispatch we create an object like:

```
private static final DispatchAsync dispatchAsync = GWT.create(DefaultDispatchAsync.class);
```

Is there any way to do this with injection, I mean how to inject this `DispatchAsync` object into other classes where we need to use it.

This is something related to `@Inject` annotation!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use Gin to inject your dispatch interface using the @Inject annotation.

First you need to configure a Gin binding for the DispatchAsync interface to an implementation in your Gin ClientModule.

```
bind(DispatchAsync.class).to(DefaultDispatchAsync.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

Once this is done, you can have Gin inject the dispatcher in your constructors.

```
class foo {
    private final DispatchAsync dispatcher;

    @Inject
    public foo(final DispatchAsync dispacher) {
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found out that (with gwt-dispatch 1.1.0) you can also have the following in your Ginjector: `@GinModules({MyGinModule.class, StandardDispatchModule.class})`, where `StandardDispatchModule.class` is a gwt-dispatch class providing standard binding for `DispatchAsync`. Then you can inject a `DispatchAsync` in the constructor of classes needing it.